# WiFi LAN speed drops to zero for 2-4 seconds every 20-60 seconds. Effectively killing the connection

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, windows-10

**My machine specs:**

- HP Envy 15'' Laptop
- Windows 10
- 8GB Ram, Inte Core i7-4700MQ 2.40GHz, 64 bit system
- WiFi adapter: Ralink RT3290 802.11bgn

**Issue**

My laptop's WiFi LAN download and upload speeds drop to zero frequently(every 20-60 seconds) for about 2-4 seconds and then they go back up again. This is not a big issue when downloading stuff or watching series online but it is so incredibly frustrating when skyping, playing online videogames etc. This is not specific to Windows 10 as it begun when I was running windows 7 or 8, can't remember.

**Proof:**

Download speed graph for a 1GB file:

[image]

Upload speed graph for a 1GB file:

[image]

**What I've tried:**

- Other computers on the same WiFi: No other of my machines have this
  problem and neither do any of my 5 flatmates.
- Other WiFi networks: This does indeed happen when connected to any other
  WiFi routers (so my laptop is the problem)
- Uninstalling the WiFi Driver and installing again. Tried thrice, did
  not solve the issue (maybe I did it wrong?)
- I even used that Windows 8 option to restore the laptop to factory
  settings while keeping only files, did not work.
- Lots of other random things that did not work either.

I need to be able to Skype but as of now it's such a painful experience every time. Normally, I can fix most of the problems on my PC by myself but this one will make me go mad.

Comment: **Warning** - please do not use obscenities in your posts. I've removed it for you. Note that other users may have flagged your post as "rude or abusive" leading to possible rep loss or suspension. Please read [Be Nice](http://superuser.com/help/be-nice): "Avoid vulgar terms and anything sexually suggestive"

Comment: It is _not_ the _Internet_ speed which is dropping, it is your Wi-Fi _LAN_ speed for a _single PC_. You clearly admit that later in the question. You should edit the title and question to reflect this. What the title and issue say is that it is the Internet, and it is not.

Comment: @DavidPostill You are right, I should have read the guidelines before posting, I was not aware of this rules. Thank you for the warning and for not deleting my post. I will keep it in mind for the future.

Comment: @RonMaupin Thanks for pointing it out, I did not know the difference in terminology. Edited it now.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you're the only person having wifi issues with HP Envy laptops.

I would grab the latest driver from the manufacturer of the Wifi card, not HP itself. That's MediaTek.

See this post on how others see this Wifi card and grabbing the latest driver:

http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Wireless-and-Networking/Ralink-RT3290-802-11bgn-Wi-Fi-Adapter-issue/td-p/4460910

I'd be contacting HP about it (though be prepared for pain when dealing with it as they will try to blame everything else except the laptop).
Is it under warranty?

In the meantime, I would suggest purchasing a USB Wifi dongle to reign back some sanity.